# Health Check for Kafka Connectors

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, health-monitoring

I have several `Kafka connectors` in production. Sometimes one of these connectors dies with the error message:

> ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and
>   unrecoverable exception
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException    at

...

> ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-0} Task is being killed and
>   will not recover until manually restarted
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:173)

The strange thing is, the REST-API for this dead connector still says that everything is ok.

What is the best practice to monitor such situation?

Comment: Which rest endpoint says it's ok? The task endpoints should say it has failed.

Comment: The log files or status endpoint should contain the stacktrace. The task is dead. The connector API will remain available for new connectors to be added

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but one way to improve your KC cluster monitoring would be to use this Kafka REST extension :
https://github.com/LoObp4ck/kafka-connect-healthchecks

And then have your monitoring periodic job to check for this endpoint to ensure all connectors tasks are running fine.
We use it in production and it does the job

The jar is also available in maven central as follows :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.loobpack.kafka-connect-healthchecks</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-connect-healthcheck-extension</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: does it also monitors broker's connectivity check, I mean if your broker goes down then will it also fail the connector or worker?